# Assigning objects as attributes to each other

Tags: python

I have two classes of objects, Top and Bottom. I create the objects in pairs and want to assign them to each other so that I can reference the other's corresponding object in my project. Is there a more elegant way to do this than my sample code?

```
class Top:
    def __init__(self,bottom):
        self.bottom = bottom

class Bottom:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
    def set_top(self,top):
        self.top = top

Top_Bottom_List = []
for i in range(5):
    Current_Bottom = Bottom()
    Current_Top = Top(Current_Bottom)
    Current_Bottom.set_top(Current_Top)
    Top_Bottom_list.append((Current_Top,Current_Bottom))
```

My problem is that I'd like to create an instance of two classes at the same time, but obviously one of them will have to be defined first or the other one won't have anything to set a value to.

Comment: I strongly urge you read [PEP 8 — the official Python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and adhere to it unless there’s good reason not to. In particular, the lack of separating newlines between your definitions makes the code quite hard to read.

Comment: Note that idiomatic Python would not define ``set_top(self, top)`` and simply replace any ``b.set_top(top)`` with ``b.top = top``. If you want to be prepared to have a setter later on, you can always add a ``property`` transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't give one class a "preferred" status over the other.

```
class Top:
    def __init__(self, bottom=None):
        self.bottom = bottom


class Bottom:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        self.top = top


def link(t, b):
    t.bottom = b
    b.top = t
    return t, b
 

top_bottom_list = [link(Top(), Bottom()) for _ in range(5)]
```

If you can't immediately pass the linked object to each other on instantiation, do *nothing* initially, then let an additional function handle pairing the two together after the fact. An additional function can take care of the instantiation as well

```
def make_pair():
    t = Top()
    b = Bottom()
    return link(t, b)

top_bottom_list = [make_pair() for _ in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that can’t be solved by another layer of indirection:

```
def create_pair():
    b = Bottom()
    t = Top(b)
    b.top = t
    return b, t

…

top_bottom_list = [create_pair() for _ in range(5)]
```

If the coupling is 1:1, you could also change the constructors:

```
class Top:
    def __init__(self, bottom = None):
        if bottom is not None:
            bottom.top = self
        self.bottom = bottom


class Bottom:
    def __init__(self, top = None):
        if top is not None:
            top.bottom = self
        self.top = top
```

And use it as:

```
def create_pair():
    b = Bottom(Top())
    return b, b.top
```

… though I’m not sure I like this code.